# Same C++ file opened in VS Code and QtCreator, error in Qt

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, qt-creator, intellisense, include-path

So I am trying to work on the Godot game engine and I have a file open in both VS Code (left of the image) and QtCreator (right of the image). In VS Code in this file, I dont get any issues and the functions `strlen` and `memcpy` are both functions pulled from the correct place, `string.h`, however in QtCreator, the functions are pulled from a file called `cstring` and I don't understand why. Could this be an intellisense issue? I've setup my include paths in both VS Code and QtCreator to be the exact same. Could anyone know why this would be happening?

Note that I've tried to add std:: infront of these functions to no effect.

[VSCode vs QtCreator error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgtLH.png)

For reference, here is my `c_cpp_properties.json` in VS Code:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/godot-cpp/include/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/godot-cpp/gen/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/core/**",
                // "${workspaceFolder}/source/godot-cpp/include/godot_cpp/variant/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/modules/**"
                // "${workspaceFolder}/source/godot/core/**",
                // "${workspaceFolder}/source/games/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            // "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}"
            // "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

And my QtCreator `.includes` file has the same directories and files.

Comment: I would bet a coin that QtCreator does not use the same compiler... That being said C++ uses namespaces to avoid name collision and because of that any header from the standard C++ library may be silently included from any other include file, and `<cstring>` **is** one. So it is not a surprise that it comes into the play here.

Comment: the functions it marked red are usually imported automatically by some compilers. MSVC for example. I guess QtCreator does not. Which is why you need to explicitly include the files which contain the declarations of the functions such as <cstring>

Comment: Any way to see what compiler QtCreator uses, or how I can change it? And also I tried to put ```#include <string.h>``` at the top of the document but still had no effect on the issue.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-tool-chains.html

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. Looks like VS Code is using the same compiler for C and C++ as QtCreator is. Any other ideas on why this might be happening?